# Doing a "one vs others" iteration through Bash script arguments

Tags: bash

I want to run a Bash script like this:

```
./myscript.sh A B C D E F
```

and then in the script I want to have a loop that will run these commands:

```
somecommand -x A -y B C D E F
somecommand -x B -y A C D E F
somecommand -x C -y A B D E F
somecommand -x D -y A B C E F
somecommand -x E -y A B C D F
somecommand -x F -y A B C D E
```

What's the best way to do this? In python I would do something like:

```
for i, first in enumerate(sys.argv[1:]):
    others = sys.argv[1:i] + sys.argv[i+1:]
    do_command(first, others)
```

But I'm not sure how to do something like this in Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it very similarly in bash, using indirect expansion (`"${!argnum}"`) to get individual arguments, and an array-slicing-like syntax to get ranges of them (`"${@:startarg:numargs}"` and `"${@:startarg}"`). Something like this:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    somecommand -x "${!i}" -y "${@:1:i-1}" "${@:i+1}"
done
```

If you want to use an explicit `others` array, create it like this:

```
others=("${@:1:i-1}" "${@:i+1}")
```